# Joomla 3: applying custom module style doesn't work

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

I'm trying to set custom style for Joomla module. I have created the file:

> `modules.php`   in  `/templates/MY_TEMPLATE_NAME/html` directory.

Content of this file below:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

function modChrome_custom($module, &$params, &$attribs)
{
     echo '<h3>test style chrome</h3>';
}
```

Now, I try to output module from my template with this style. I do it this way:

```
 <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-1" style="custom"  />
```

But it looks like my custom style is not applying to the module and all I see is a standard module layout. Did I miss something?

Comment: Your code looks ok and should be working properly. I even tested it on my local protostar and it works as it should

Comment: Are you sure you have named the file **modules.php** and not **module.php** (note the `s` on the end). Try using a different name for the chrome as `custom` might already be taken

Answer (score 4):

if you change the style of your module in the backend it will overwrite the style given to your jdoc:include in the index.php.

Go to your Backend->Modules, open Modul, open last Tab "Advanced", scroll down to last item "Module Style", check wich style is associated to your module.

To use the style added to your jdoc:include you need to set the backend style to "From Template: Inherited".